# Green function and Fourier series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I would like to understand what is wrong with the following computation. Indeed the result appears rather trivial. I have the following differential equation
$$
   y''(t,t')+z(t)y(t,t')=\delta(t-t')
$$
for the the Green function $y(t,t')$. I know that
$$
   z(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{i\omega_n t}.
$$
I apply a Fourier transform to the differential equation and obtain
$$
    -\omega^2 \tilde y(\omega,t')+\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n\tilde y(\omega+\omega_n,t')=e^{i\omega t'}.
$$
Using the shift operator $T=e^{\omega_n\frac{d}{d\omega}}$ I can rewrite such an equation as
$$
    \left[-\omega^2+\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{\omega_n\frac{d}{d\omega}}\right]\tilde y(\omega,t')=e^{i\omega t'}
$$
that I formally invert to obtain
$$
    \tilde y(\omega,t')=\frac{e^{i\omega t'}}{-\omega^2+\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{i\omega_n t'}+i0}.
$$
I recognize the Fourier series of $z(t')$ and finally
$$
    \tilde y(\omega,t')=\frac{e^{i\omega t'}}{-\omega^2+z(t')+i0}.
$$
You can realize that this equation is wrong by setting $t'=0$. In this case you get the trivial result
$$
   \tilde y(\omega,0)=\frac{1}{-\omega^2+z(0)+i0}
$$
that is not solution of the equation we started with. This can be easily checked by transforming it back to $t$. Why?

Another relevant question associated with this problem is:

> If I know the solution of the equation for the Green function at
>   $t'=0$ how can I reconstruct the full solution for $t'\ne 0$?

Comment: "not solution of the equation we started with" -- because the function $y$ you have at the end is the Fourier transform of $y$ you had originally? It's confusing (to me) when the same notation is used for two things.

Comment: @127.0.9.6 : Thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: I think the problem is that $\tilde y$ does not satisfy the [algebraic] equation from which you obtained it. I.e., it's on the Fourier transform side. Unfortunately I am not familiar with this use of differential operator in the exponent, so cannot comment on its validity.